# Files don't show unless I relaunch Finder

Tags: macos, download, finder

I have an old G5. When I download a file, click, and select "Open in Finder", it sometimes doesn't show all the files until I "relaunch" Finder.  Same thing with the trash: I can't see what was in there until I relaunch Finder.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?